# MergeError: Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O'), both sides must have numeric dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

I am looking to merge two pd dataframes using merge_asof because I want to merge my two tables not only on dates but on the closest date found.

```
def get_historical_pe(data, stock):
    item_data = {}
    for i,j in data['Earnings']['History'].items():
        item_data[j['date']]=[j['epsActual'], j['reportDate']]
    df = pd.DataFrame(item_data).T
    df.columns = ['EPS', 'Release date']
    df.dropna(subset=['EPS'], how='all', inplace=True)
    df['date2'] = df.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    print(type(df['date2'][0]))
    df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d')
    df.loc[date.today()] = [df.loc[df.index.max(),'EPS'], 'TTM', date.today()]
    stocksplit = stock.split('.')
    if stocksplit[1] == 'US':
        stockPricesdata = yf.Ticker(stocksplit[0])
    else:
        stockPricesdata = yf.Ticker(stock)
    stockPrices = stockPricesdata.history(period="max")['Close']
    stockPricesdf = pd.DataFrame(stockPrices)
    stockPricesdf['date2'] = stockPricesdf.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')
    tol = pd.Timedelta('1 day')
    st = pd.merge_asof(
        left=df,
        right=stockPricesdf,
        on='date2',
        direction='nearest',
        tolerance=tol
        )
    
    return st
```

However I am getting an error: MergeError: Incompatible merge dtype, dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('O'), both sides must have numeric dtype
however I checker to change the type of my merge column to the same type .. I do not understand what am I doing wrong

Could you please help me.
Thx you

Comment: How working if change `stockPricesdf['date2'] = stockPricesdf.index.astype('datetime64[ns]')` to `stockPricesdf['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(stockPricesdf.index)` ?

Comment: Exact same result ;)

Comment: Hmm, maybe bug, is possible upgrade pandas?

Comment: Updated .. relaunched Anaconda .. but still the same error. What is weired is that if I print the data type of my columns I get for both: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Comment: Is `stockPricesdf['date2'].dtype` same like `df['date2'].dtype` ?

Comment: Yes I get datetime64[ns], datetime64[ns] for both

Comment: No idea, unfortuantely :(

Comment: Thx for the help ;)